# whereHas con with en Laravel no funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando utilizar whereHas y with juntos para filtrar un registro en laravel, pero no se porque no funciona.

Mis tablas son:

1. Tipo: id | tipo
2. DiaTipo: id | tipo_id | dia_id
3. Dia: id | reg_dia_id
4. RegDia: id
5. DiaTipoFactura: dia_tipo_id | factura_id
6. Factura: id

- La tabla "Tipo" tiene relacion uno a muchos con la tabla "DiaTipo"
- La tabla "Dia" tiene relacion uno a muchos con la tabla "DiaTipo"
- La tabla "RegDia" tiene relacion uno a muchos con la tabla "Dia"
- La tabla "DiaTipoFactura" es una tabla intermedia de una relacion muchos a muchos de las tablas "Factura" y "DiaTipo"

Los datos que tengo en cada tabla son:

1. Tipo: (1 | A)
2. DiaTipo: (1 | 1 | 1), (1 | 1 | 2)
3. Dia: (1 | 1), (1 | 2), (1 | 3)
4. RegDia: (1), (2), (3)

Los modelos que tengo son:

```
class Tipo extends Model
{
    public function dia_tipo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DiaTipo::class);
    }
}

class DiaTipo extends Model
{
    public function dia()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Dia::class, 'dia_id');
    }
}

class Dia extends Model
{
    public function reg_dia()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RegDia::class, 'reg_dia_id');
    }
}
```

Y la consulta que hago para filtrar el "reg_dia_id" en 1:

```
Tipo::whereHas('dia_tipo.dia', function() {
    $query->where('reg_dia_id',1);
})->with('dia_tipo.dia');
```

Pero me sale este resultado:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tipo": "A",
    "dia_tipo": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "tipo_id": 1,
        "dia": {
          "id": 1,
          "reg_dia_id": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "tipo_id": 1,
        "dia": {
          "id": 1,
          "reg_dia_id": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Como ven, tengo `"reg_dia_id": 2`, pero eso no deberia estar ahi porque utilize el `whereHas` y me deberia mostrar solo `"reg_dia_id": 1`

**Edit**
Lo que quiero es que se filtre `"reg_dia_id": 1` en la tabla `Dia`

Gracias a todos!

Comment: @BetaM lo hice asi porque tambien estoy utilizando el id de esa tabla diatipo, ya que esa tabla tiene una relacion muchos a muchos con otra tabla

Comment: @BetaM ok, tambien pondre las otras tablas que mencione con las relaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El modelo que declaraste para tu tabla intermedia no esta apegado a las indicaciones de [Laravel al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) (*aunque tampoco es requerido que exista*).

Te hago las siguientes observaciones:

1. La relación entre: *dia, tipo y diatipo* es de muchos a muchos
2. Como *no es necesario* un modelo para *diatipo* entonces para esta respuesta yo lo descartaré quedando [únicamente lo siguiente](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

Modelo Tipo

```
class Tipo extends Model
{
    public function dias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dia::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Dia

```
class Dia extends Model
{
    public function tipos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tipo::class);
    }
}
```

3. Aqui es muy importante analizar si tus tablas siguen las convenciones esperadas por Eloquent, en caso de que no entonces deberás [agregar un segundo, tercer y cuarto argumento](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) según sea la situación.

Entonces la consulta puede quedar así:

```
Tipo::with(['dias' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereRegDiaId(1);
}])->get();
```

Recomiendo leas sobre [*constraining eager loads*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Me funciono asi, pero como te habia dicho, la tabla "DiaTipo" tiene una relacion muchos a muchos con "Factura", como se haria en esa parte? Tengo que crear el modelo de "DiaTipo"?

Comment: @bemoba1437 como dije al inicio de mi respuesta si vas a agregar un modelo para la tabla intermedia entonces guíate de los pasos indicados en la doc. oficial

Comment: Lo vere, gracias!